# How to publish an ASP.NET MVC application to a free host

Tags: asp.net-mvc, publish, publishing

I'm building an ASP.NET MVC application and I'm trying to deploy it on a free host (0000free) which does support ASP.NET. I tried a couple of things, but none of them worked (i.e. I only see the directory structure when I browse to my web site):

1. Publishing to a local folder and then copying the published files via ftp over to my host (in the public_html directory).
2. Publishing via ftp to the root folder: ftp.mywebsite.com
3. Publishing via ftp to the public_html folder: ftp.mywebsite.com/public_html

Usually I would just drop the html files in the public_html folder, but I'm getting the feeling that the deployment process for an MVC application is slightly different. Do I have to modify the `Web.config` or some other filer? How does one usually deploy an MVC application (on a free host)?

**Update:**
I have learned that the host uses Mono and supports .NET 4.0, but I'm still not able to deploy.

I have Visual Studio 2010 and I used its Publish Feature (i.e. right click on the project name and click publish) and I tried several things:

1. Publish method: FTP to the root folder.
2. Publish method: FTP to the publich_html folder.
3. Publish method: File System to the root folder.
4. Publish method: File System to the publich_html folder.
5. Publish method: File System to a local directory on my computer and then FTP to root and also tried the public_html folder.
6. I went into the cPanel (control panel) to try and see if ASP.NET has to be added/enabled for my web site, but I didn't see anything there.
7. I can't browse to Index.aspx nor can I redirect to it from index.html (as suggested from other posts on the [host forum](http://0000free.com/forum/thread-3055-post-16903.html)), right now I have a link from index.html to Index.aspx but it's not working either (see http://www.mydevarmy.com)
8. I've also tried renaming Index.aspx to Default.aspx, but that doesn't work either.

The search utility of the forum of the host is somewhat weak, so I use google to search their forum: http://www.google.com/search?q=publish+asp.net+site%3A0000free.com%2Fforum%2F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a

I've been reading [Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](http://apress.com/book/view/1430228865) and they have a chapter about publishing, but it doesn't provide any specific information with respect to the location of publishing, this is all they say (and it's not very helpful in my case):

> **Where Should I Put My Application?**
>   You can deploy your application to any
>   folder on the server. When IIS first
>   installs, it automatically creates a
>   folder for a web site called Default
>   Web Site at c:\Inetpub\wwwroot\, but
>   you shouldn’t feel any obligation to
>   put your application files there. It’s
>   very common to host applications on a
>   different physical drive from the
>   operating system (e.g., in
>   e:\websites\ example.com). It’s
>   entirely up to you, and may be
>   influenced by concerns such as how you
>   plan to back up the server.

Here is the error I get when I try to view my Index.aspx page:

```
Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. (/home/devarmy/public_html/Web.config line 1)

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized attribute 'targetFramework'. (/home/devarmy/public_html/Web.config line 1)
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement.DeserializeElement (System.Xml.XmlReader reader, Boolean serializeCollectionKey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.DoDeserializeSection (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection.DeserializeSection (System.Xml.XmlReader reader) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSectionInstance (System.Configuration.SectionInfo config, Boolean createDefaultInstance) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSectionCollection.get_Item (System.String name) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.Configuration.GetSection (System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName, System.String path, System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName, System.String path) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.GetWebApplicationSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.get_CompilationConfig () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Build (System.Web.VirtualPath vp) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.Web.VirtualPath virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetCompiledType (System.String virtualPath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.InitType (System.Web.HttpContext context) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Comment: Shouldn't this kind of question be asked on **serverfault.com**? They are admin oriented and not programming...

Comment: @Robert I googled their forum (`publish asp.net site:0000free.com/forum/`) and I found that they're using Mono (not sure what that means). Another person was seeing the directory tree too, but fixed it by [adding an index.php redirect script](http://0000free.com/forum/thread-3055-post-16903.html) and it also seems that ASP.NET projects have to be compiled for mono... it's all a bit confusing.

Comment: @Mono is a Linux version of .net. I don't think it's going to be so easy to deploy your Asp.net MVC application to this host. The think is you see they don't actually support Asp.net. They just support Mono which is a Linux post of Asp.net. Sorry to tell you this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your hosting provider supports ASP.NET MVC then your deployment process shouldn't be any different than the one for a normal ASP.NET application. If it doesn't you could attempt a [bin-deployment](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx). And here's [another article](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: I know the host supports ASP.NET, but does it also have to support ASP.NET MVC (I thought they're the same thing)?

Comment: As far as I read the question, he is doing the **Deploy** command from within Visual Studio. He tried several options but they didn't work. I suppose he needs to contact hosting provider what steps to take to deploy an Asp.net application. I can't find any info on their forum about it.

Comment: @Lirik: Yes they are the same. As long as host supports Asp.net it should as well support Asp.net MVC. It's just 3 additional DLLs that can be deployed along with your application.

Comment: @Robert, in what folder (on the server) do I deploy the project with the DLLs and all? publich_html?

Comment: @Lirik: I don't know about that since this information is host specific. Usually developer just deploys in whatever folder that's configured as an application in IIS. *public_html* sounds to me that it's more a folder for simple static content than running dynamic applications.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the Mono version does not support MVC, so I had to change my host to one that supports ASP.NET MVC. I had to dish out some cash, but "good hosting" isn't free. Anyway, thanks for the help everybody!

Comment: Ok. I see you've found this info already (you can ignore my upper comment about Mono). +1 for the info about the steps you've taken. BTW: Since Microsoft stack requires for money licenses it's going to be jolly hard to get a free host on these technologies if at all.

Comment: @Robert Koritnik, it's almost impossible to get a free ASP.NET host! Not making a shameless plug here, but I found a 30%-off coupon for Arvixe hosting and I was able to get 2 years of hosting for $84 ($3.50 a month). I don't have to deal with Mono anymore and that makes me happy!

Comment: Good for you. And if your web app can generate some money you can hope to generate enough to pay hosting out of that. But it's normal that Asp.net hosting isn't free. Windows license costs, Linux doesn't. SQL server cost lots more, MySql's free. Hence some of them provide the free SQL Express edition... Which is always free but has limits that are high enough for starters.